# MVC3 pass @model to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, partial

I have two partial views which are exactly the same, but for the @model.

@model Project.Models.X

@model Project.Models.Y

How could I pass this model type to the view so that I can use the same view for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a ViewModel Z, which passed to View.
If you want to pass model X or Y, just passed that to Z then pass model Z to View.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is best practice, but you could also use HTML.RenderAction to call your controller and have it return a PartialViewResult with whatever model you want, like so:

```
  @{Html.RenderAction("MyPartialAction", "MyController", new { someID = 1 });}
```

and

```
 public PartialViewResult MyPartialAction(int? someID)
 {
        return PartialView("MyPartial",SomeModel);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make both classes implement the same interface, and use the interface as your model.

As suggested by Tim: If possible you could also inherit from the same base class. Although this is not always possible, using the interface approach is mostly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly like gandil: Create a ViewModel Z but use Automapper to map from Y and X. That way you can keep your UI models clean and DRY.