# Getting data for Partial View MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I have a partial view in MVC 3 .NET. 
Every time I render the partial view, I get an error saying the Model is null. I would like for the partial view to get the data itself without passing data to it. Is it possible?

Edit
@html.partial("_partialView")

In the Partial View @Model is null and if I try to access any property of @Model, it crashes since it is null.
So I need that everytime I call @html.partial("_partialView"), the partial view to get the data from the server and populate @Model.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: It's completely possible. But can you provide your code so we can help your specific problem?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426381/mvc3-pass-model-to-partial-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you don't use model data inside of view, but if you do - feel free to provide model :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `@model SomeModelType` line somewhere at the beginning of your view and also all calls to `@Model.SomeProperty` (they are the actual cause of exception).
Remove all this stuff if you don't want to use model inside your partial view.

Comment: I do want to use the model. But it is null since I'm not passing data to the partial view, I want it to get it itself.

Comment: How do you want it to get the model? If you have not passed a model in partial view, it will be null inside it and you can't do anything because `WebViewPage<TModel>.Model` property is read-only (may be you can make some customizations in ASP.NET MVC infrastructure, but I don't think that it's worth effort).

You can supply your model to the view in another way, not via `WebViewPage<TModel>.Model` property, but I don't think it will be good design.